# Jquery - tell when the hash changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fragment-identifier

I'm trying to make my site respond correctly to the back button.  I've saved that hash of what I want it to do, but I don't know the hook for jQuery to be able to tell when the hash changes.  It's not .ready(), because the page doesn't reload.  What do I use?

**Edit for a bit of clarity:**

I'm using an iframe, so I can't tell when someone clicks a link.  It's on the same subdomain, so i'm able to see it's filepath, and am saving it so you can bookmark.  Unfortunately by saving it as a hash, my back button now fails to reload, which fails to reload the iframe, so my back button is essentially broken.  If there was a way to tell when the URI changes, I could check it against the iframe address and change it if they don't match.

All I need is a way to check if the URI has changed.  Is there a .change() for the URI?  Something along those lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the document is ready, you examine the hash and alter the page appropriately.

> I don't know the hook for jQuery to be able to tell when the hash changes

You can intercept your hash anchors' click events and respond appropriately as opposed to waiting for a "the hash has changed" event (which doesn't exist).

Some approaches create a "the hash has changed" event by inspecting `window.location.hash` on a timer.

Comment: i'll do the timer if everything else fails, thanks!  Let me see if anyone has a way that doesn't involve a timer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [History Event](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/historyevent) plugin.

Comment: They use a time too.  I guess that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 2):

Ben 'the cowboy' Alman wrote a cross platform plugin for hash changes

http://benalman.com/news/2010/07/jquery-hashchange-event-v13/

I dont know if your using it inside of the iframe or what, but if you were to use it outside the iframe it would be like

```
$(function(){
    $(window).hashchange(function(){
       //Insert event to be triggered on has change.
       changeIframeContent(window.location.hash);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [solution](http://www.bennadel.com/index.cfm?dax=blog:1520.view) of Ben Nadel which is in binding events to non-DOM objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is'nt a buitin way to watch for hash changes, in firefox you could use watch method, but as far as I know it isnt default, so you can hack it writing something like (see below)

```
function setWatchHashChanges(functionObject)
{
    if(window.location.watch)
    {
        window.location.watch('hash', function(e){functionObject(e);return e;});
    } else {
        if(!setWatchHasnChanges.hash)
        {
            setWatchHasnChanges.hash = window.locaton.hash;
        } else {
            setInterval(function(){
            if(setWatchHasnChanges.hash!== window.locaton.hash)
            {
                setWatchHasnChanges.hash = window.locaton.hash;
                functionObject(setWatchHasnChanges.hash);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```