# Handle URL fragment identifier (anchor) change event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, fragment-identifier, hashchange

How can I write the Javascript callback code that will be executed on any changes in the URL fragment identifier (anchor)?

For example from `http://example.com#a` to `http://example.com#b`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Google Custom Search Engines use a timer to check the hash against a previous value, whilst the child iframe on a seperate domain updates the parent's location hash to contain the size of the iframe document's body.  When the timer catches the change, the parent can resize the iframe to match that of the body so that scrollbars aren't displayed.

Something like the following achieves the same:

```
var storedHash = window.location.hash;
window.setInterval(function () {
    if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
        storedHash = window.location.hash;
        hashChanged(storedHash);
    }
}, 100); // Google uses 100ms intervals I think, might be lower
```

Google Chrome 5, Safari 5, [Opera 10.60](http://twitter.com/dstorey/status/15102284544), [Firefox 3.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) and [Internet Explorer 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288209(VS.85).aspx) **all** support the `hashchange` event:

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) // does the browser support the hashchange event?
    window.onhashchange = function () {
        hashChanged(window.location.hash);
    }
```

and putting it together:

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) { // event supported?
    window.onhashchange = function () {
        hashChanged(window.location.hash);
    }
}
else { // event not supported:
    var storedHash = window.location.hash;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
            storedHash = window.location.hash;
            hashChanged(storedHash);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

jQuery also has a plugin that will check for the hashchange event and provide its own if necessary - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/.

**EDIT**: Updated browser support (again).

Comment: for completeness, add `var storedHash = window.location.hash;` to the putting-it-together summary block. Btw: Nowadays this is called polyfill I think.

Comment: Nowadays you can listen to the `hashChange` on `window` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change

Comment: @AndyE I did read the answer, I missed the small note, and I have never seen events that look like `hashChanged(storedHash);`

Comment: @TimoHuovinen: `hashChanged`, in this case, is intended to be a function implemented by a developer using this code.  The answer here just demonstrates how one may monitor the hash for changes where the `onhashchange` event is not available, and combines the event-based and timer-based approaches to provide a universal solution. My point is that the answer that you linked to adds absolutely nothing to the answer here ;-).  They provide the same basic information, even the link to Ben Alman's jQuery plugin.  The only difference is that I provided a pure JS solution in my answer.

Comment: @AndyE ok, wasn't aware of the requirement to implement that function, thank you for clarifying

Comment: I was looking for some lightweight JS router, but this did the job nicely. Also eliminated all dependencies :)

Answer (score 12):

An event listener can be added for the [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) event, which will fire whenever the fragment identifier changes:

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
  // Perform action
  // [...]
})
```

I would recommend this approach instead of overwriting `window.onhashchange`, otherwise you will block the event for other plugins.

Looking at the global browser usage today, a fallback is longer needed, as modern browsers support this event.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see in other SO questions, the only workable cross-browser solution is a timer. Check out [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369241/jquery-tell-when-the-hash-changes) for example.

Answer (score 3):

`setInterval()` is only universal solution for now. But there are some light in the future in form of [hashchange event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#history-traversal)

Comment: FYI: `onhashchange` event's [documentation at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

Answer (score 2):

(Just for the record.) The YUI3 "hashchange" synthetic event does more or less the same thing as the accepted answer

```
YUI().use('history-hash', function (Y) {
  Y.on('hashchange', function (e) {
    // Handle hashchange events on the current window.
  }, Y.config.win);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way that worked just fine for me with jQuery.
I've added a animation to scroll to the anchor element aswell:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
     var origEvent = e.originalEvent;
         var elementToBeClicked = $('a[href^="'+window.location.hash+'"]').click();  
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: 200
    }, 100);
});
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more info from this

[Mutation event types](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents)

> The mutation event module is designed
>   to allow notification of any changes
>   to the structure of a document,
>   including attr and text modifications.

Comment: This is about DOM changes.