# cross-domain iframe resizer?

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm looking for a good cross-domain iframe resizing script that adjusts its height based on its content. I have access to the html/css for the source of the iframe as well. Is there any out there?

Comment: check out this easy solution instead:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024574/get-and-set-iframe-content-height-auto-resize-dynamically-easy-solution-expanding

Comment: Is it me or do all these answers require you to add a script to the *external* page ?

Answer (score 36):

If your users are on modern browsers, you can solve this quite easily with [postMessage in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/#web-messaging). Here's a quick solution which works well:

The iframe page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight, 'http://target.domain.com');">
  <h3>Got post?</h3>
  <p>Lots of stuff here which will be inside the iframe.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The parent page which contains the iframe (and would like to know its height):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeCrossDomainIframe(id, other_domain) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      if (event.origin !== other_domain) return; // only accept messages from the specified domain
      if (isNaN(event.data)) return; // only accept something which can be parsed as a number
      var height = parseInt(event.data) + 32; // add some extra height to avoid scrollbar
      iframe.height = height + "px";
    }, false);
  }
</script>
```

```html
<iframe src='http://example.com/page_containing_iframe.html' id="my_iframe" onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('my_iframe', 'http://example.com');">
</iframe>
```

Comment: It worked for me; only drawback is that the remote iFramed site also needs to be edited and this will not work if that is not editable

Comment: Tried this in Chrome (version 56.0.2924.87) without success. Don't get any errors, but no resizing is performed either.

Answer (score 15):

Having failed to find a solution that dealt with all the different use-cases for this I ended up writing a simple js lib that supports both width and height, resizing content and multiple iframes on one page.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: This library is very impressive and seems to solve all others problems I encountered with the others solutions. Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 1):

[EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net)  can do just this :) 
[This blog pos](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/resize-iframe-based-on-content/)t explains the gist of it

Comment: I just took a look and it seems way out of my expertise.

Comment: See http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/resize-iframe-based-on-content/ for an explanation - there really aren't an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

The first script on this page - the one  using postMessage in HTML5 - also works for iframes on mobile - by resizing the iframe to the content - for example syndicating cross-domain - you can easily scroll in iphones or android, in a way that's not possible with iframes otherwise

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I ended up using html5's message passing mechanism wrapped in a [jQuery pluging](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) that makes it compatible with older browsers using various methods (some of them described in this thread).

The end solution is very simple.

**On the host (parent) page:**

```
// executes when a message is received from the iframe, to adjust 
// the iframe's height
    $.receiveMessage(
        function( event ){
            $( 'my_iframe' ).css({
                height: event.data
            });
    });

// Please note this function could also verify event.origin and other security-related checks.
```

**On the iframe page:**

```
$(function(){

    // Sends a message to the parent window to tell it the height of the 
    // iframe's body

    var target = parent.postMessage ? parent : (parent.document.postMessage ? parent.document : undefined);

    $.postMessage(
        $('body').outerHeight( true ) + 'px',
        '*',
        target
    );

});
```

I've tested this on Chrome 13+, Firefox 3.6+, IE7, 8 and 9 on XP and W7, safari on OSX and W7. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a whole different solution to cross domain iframe resizing.  It involves procuring a copy of the target page that you will put in your iframe, writing it locally, then putting that copy into your iframe and resizing based on same domain access to the dom inside the frame.

an example follows:

```
<?php
            if(isset($_GET['html'])) $blogpagehtml = file_get_contents(urldecode($_GET['html']));
            else $blogpagehtml = file_get_contents('http://r****d.wordpress.com/');
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $doc->loadHTML($blogpagehtml);
            libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
            $anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
            foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
                 $anchorlink=$anchor->getAttribute("href");
                 if(strpos($anchorlink,"http://r****d.wordpress")===false) $anchor->setAttribute("target","_top");
                 else $anchor->setAttribute("href","formatimportedblog.php?html=".urlencode($anchorlink));        
            }
            $newblogpagehtml = $doc->saveHTML();
            $token = rand(0,50);
            file_put_contents('tempblog'.$token.'.html',$newblogpagehtml);


?>

            <iframe id='iframe1' style='width:970px;margin:0 auto;' src='tempblog<?php echo $token; ?>.html' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');" height="5600"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -2):

Following code worked for me:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById(id);  
iframe.height = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
```

Tested on Opera 11, IE 8 9, FF 8, Chrome 16

Comment: This only works if the iframe src is on the same domain as the parent.