# get and set iframe content height auto resize dynamically easy solution expanding tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, resize, height

I'm using this script: [Set iframe content height to auto resize dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024574/get-and-set-iframe-content-height-auto-resize-dynamically-easy-solution-expandin), only 3 iframes I have, and this script only works with one and not with the 3, what do I do?

Here is a snippet showing the iframe in my page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function setIframeHeight(iframeId) {

        var ifDoc, ifRef = document.getElementById( iframeId );
        try {
            ifDoc = ifRef.contentWindow.document.documentElement;
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ifDoc = ifRef.contentDocument.documentElement;
            } catch (ee) { } 
        }

        if (fDoc) {
            ifRef.height = 1;
            ifRef.height = ifDoc.scrollHeight;
       }

</script>

<iframe id="contentFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%"
    src="http://ivomenezes.com/frames/home.php"
    onload="setIframeHeight('contentFrame')"> </iframe>
```