# How can I hide or color iframe scrollbar in Firefox and Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

How do I hide (and color) the iframe scrollbar in Firefox and Internet Explorer with css or Javascript? I am using height auto iframe content and it is working fine but scrollbar is showing (except in Chrome). I am using [iframe height auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606920/cross-domain-iframe-resizer) for cross domain height auto.

Comment: Why would you hide it and colour it at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's generally easier to answer questions like this if you provide the code that you have so far.

Comment: No i am saying color is optional

Answer (score 1):

I recall having a similar issue a while back , depending on your needs
I would try using :

```
overflow-y:hidden;
```

in the css or the

```
scrolling="no"
```

inside the iframe element. ( This should work)

If all else fails , here's a little hack , set the parent div slightly smaller width than the child div and set its css like so:

```
    .parent {

        overflow-x:hidden;
        width:486px;
        height:300px;
    }
    .child {
        width:500px;
        height:auto;
    }
```

Then to make it look even slightly better play with the css eg: set the border right and it will look as though you never did such a hack , but as i said before , try the scrolling="no" first , as this latter method would probably be frowned upon by some, however in my defense it is a solution to a problem.

Happy Coding.

Comment: where i am added overflow hidden in iframe or its parent div

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script that's taking care of the height so you don't need to scroll, you can simply turn scrolling off so they're not there, getting in the way:

```
<iframe src="//www.abc.net.au/" scrolling="no" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

`scrolling="no"` does the trick.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rt2bf/

Comment: In the fiddle there's no scrollbars when `scrolling="no"` is added. If you're seeing a different result, can we have a look at your code, in a fiddle, or at your site where this is happening?