# history.pushState does not trigger 'popstate' event

Tags: html, history.js

Why

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', () => alert('pop'));

window.history.pushState(null, '', '/foo');
```

does not alert `pop` ?

NB: Testing on latest chrome

--

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_popstate_event):

> A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes. If the history entry being activated was created by a call to pushState or affected by a call to replaceState, the popstate event's state property contains a copy of the history entry's state object.

So why my `pushState` does not trigger the `popstate` event?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The paragraph you reference is a little ambiguous. Reading the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Example) on the same page, it is clear that popstate is only triggered when the user clicks the back button, not when the script calls `pushState()`.

Comment: popstate is also triggered when the user presses the forward button.

Comment: pushstate does trigger popstate! Hence "A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes"!

Comment: @AlexGill Do you have a test-case that demonstrates this behavior? Something like:

`
window.onpopstate = function(e) { alert('popstate'); }
history.pushState(null, '');
`

Comment: popstate is *also* triggered with `window.location.hash = "<some new hash>"`.  Dmitri Farkov's answer below mentions this detail and it's important I think.

Answer (score 65):

You can manually trigger `popstate` event on `window` every time you call `history.pushState()`.

```
history.pushState(state, '', url);

var popStateEvent = new PopStateEvent('popstate', { state: state });
dispatchEvent(popStateEvent);
```

Comment: Excellent answer, Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Thanks @sgtpep! This successfully triggers `addEventListener('popstate', event)`

Answer (score 14):

You are reading MDN's "guide page" which is not meant to be normative.

Consider reading MDN's ["documentation page" for `WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate) instead:

> Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. **The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action** such as a clicking on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript). And the event is only triggered when the user navigates between two history entries for the same document.

Another undocumented way of triggering `popstate` is by direct manipulation of the `window.location` object.

```js
// this also triggers popstate 
window.location.hash = "#some-new-hash"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because of the window.location.hash thing

Comment: No state will be passed in this way, it's only good for a stateless operation

Comment: Another good explanation of how the event works can be found here https://www.codeguage.com/courses/js/events-popstate-event

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
var url = "http://awesome.website.net/route/to/paradise";
window.history.pushState({}, "", url);
window.history.pushState({}, "", url); // yes twice
window.history.back();
```

It will trigger a soft-navigation via 'popstate' event and no HTTP request.

Comment: Is this what all of the front-end frameworks do, too?

Comment: That sucks, because you end up with redundant forward state. No, frameworks don't do that. They just have good code that calls the same callback on both `popstate` and after `pushState`.

Answer (score 0):

Document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate says:

> Note that just calling `history.pushState()` or `history.replaceState()` won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event will been triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back or forward button (or calling `history.back()` or `history.forward()` in JavaScript).

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this too... I think the event only fires if you have something at the top level of your data object that is distinct from the previous state.

Try this:

```
var data = {rand: Math.random()};
window.history.pushState(data, '', '/foo');
```

Comment: This doesn't call popstate either. At least not on Firefox 26.