# Simple pagination using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple pagination using Javascript (yes, I am aware of jquery plugins but I really would like to figure out how I can do this from scratch). Anyway, I'm quite close to finishing the paging but I can't quite figure out how I can make the back button work. Also, how can I add page numbers so that I can have something like: Next ... 1 2 .. 9 10 ... Last? Currently I only have next and last buttons. Here's how my code looks like currently. I know it still needs fixing but, I'll take of that later.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) { ?>
<div id="div<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;">
    <div><label>object<?php echo $i; ?></label><br/><br/></div>
</div>
<?php   $j = $i;
}
?>
<div><input type="button" id="btn_next" value="NEXT" onclick="goNext()"/></div>
<div><input type="button" style="display:none;" id="btn_back" value="BACK" onclick="goBack()"/></div>
```

I don't think there's anything in my html/php elements that need changing but I added it for more detail. Here's my current javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
if(document.getElementById('object'+i) != null) {

    if (document.getElementById('object'+i) != null && typeof(document.getElementById('object'+i)) != undefined && document.getElementById('object'+i) != "") {
        var x = document.getElementById('object'+i).style.display = 'block';
        var count5 = +i;
    }
}}

var nextArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var prevArr = [1,2,3,4,5];

function goNext(){
var max = "<?php echo $j; ?>"
var num1 = i;
var num2 = num1 + 4;
var num3 = num1 - 1;

for (var next = nextArr.length; next <= num2; next++) {
    document.getElementById('object'+next).style.display = 'block';
}

if(num2 == max){
    document.getElementById('btn_next').style.display = 'none';
}

for (var newArr= 5; newArr <= num3; newArr++)
{
    nextArr[newArr] = [newArr];
}

var quotient = num1 / 5;
if(quotient >= 1) {
    for (var value = num3; value > 0; value--) {
        document.getElementById('object'+value).style.display = 'none';
    }
}

//increment i
i = num2 + 1;

//display back if array lenght is > 5
if(nextArr.length >= 5) {
    document.getElementById('btn_back').style.display = 'block';
}}

function goBack() {
var num1 = i;
var num2 = num1 + 4;
var num3 = num1 - 1;
var num4 = num3 - 5;

i = num2+ 1;

for (var back = num4; back >= 5; back--)
{
    prevArr[back] = [back];
}

var quotient = num1 / 5;
if (quotient >= 1) {
    for(var prev = num4; prev >= 0 ; prev--)
    {
        document.getElementById('hiddendiv'+prev).style.display='block';
    }       
}}</script>
```

num1 is the first index of the next 5 items to be displayed, num2 is the last index of the next 5 items, num3 is the last index of the currently displayed items and num4 is the 1st index of the currently displayed items. The back button already does something however, I just can't put my finger on the right idea to hide the elements when the previous divs are displayed. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving a straight forward solution but this is what you can do to get it working, and pardon me I am answering this without paying attention to the code you posted.

- Have pagination links with hash for example `<a href="#page1">1</a>` etc
- On Page load add listener for hashchange. A simple way to capture back button press to detect [hash change in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change)
- When hashchanges you fire AJAX call to fetch data(from PHP)
- Server can return either `JSON` on HTML fragment. Depending on type of data, you build the template in the callback.
- Append/Prepend/Alter Search result DOM in the callback.

Additionally, if you want to make it efficient and cache previously shown result, you can maintain a JSON to hold previous search result. Add some logic to check if back button was pressed just pop out the data from JSON and display it. Although, keep in mind that this approach can backfire in some cases.