# Call function on navigate with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using ChartJS to create a chart on a page in angular. I am running into the issue of when I navigate to a new page, and back to the original page, the JS is not called again.

Is there a way to call a javascript function or file every time an angular page navigates? I guess I'd then just see if my selector exists on the page and then call the function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Call on every page:
    (function ($) {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $(".bubbleScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar({
                theme: "rounded-dots"
            });

            $(".hBubbleScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar({
                //theme: "minimal-dark",
                theme: "rounded-dots-dark",
                axis: "x",
                advanced: {autoExpandHorizontalScroll: true},
                mouseWheelPixels: 150

            });

        });
    })(jQuery);

// on all chart pages:


    var ctx = $('#chart-TicketsResolved').get(0).getContext("2d");
    var data = [
        {
            value: 300,
            color: "#50AD7E",
            label: "Resolved"
        },
        {
            value: 200,
            color: "#d9d9d9",
            label: "Open"
        }
    ];
    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Gauge(data);
});
```

Comment: You should create chart using angular way, by creating directive and options should in controller.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. I'm still new to angular. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your function by listenning to `window.hashchanged` event.

```
window.onhashchange = function () {
  console.log('my function runs every time the # hash changes');
}
```

See more here: [How to detect URL change in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change)