# Script Parse on Page Reload

Tags: javascript

I have CKEditor loading on AJAX calls with a Script Parser running Scripts at the onComplete of the AJAX calls.  This is working great.  I then added a window.onshashchange event to my site, and this then recalls via AJAX the sites content as expected.  This loads the CKEditor fine.

My problem occurs where you use the Query String and Address Bar directly.  This does not fire the onhashchange event.  CKeditor does not load and the textarea is a standard textarea because the scripts have no been parsed.

This only occurs when you click the Address Bar, enter a pathhit enter or do a reload of the browser.  It does not occur when you use the back and forward buttons.

What event triggers upon entering on the address bar with a query. As this is not an onhashchange event, I need to tie a handler to my function.

Comment: I think this post can helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6390389/1102416

Comment: i have an onhashchange eventhandler, it works fine.  This is not triggered when someone reloads the page, nor is it triggered is someone pastes a link into the address bar and hits enter.