# Detect an URL change in a SPA

Tags: javascript, dom-events, single-page-application

I would like to listen to path changes in a SPA which is not maintained by me.

I found one solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819548/7042552

But still, it seems kind of "hacky" to me - but still my implementation is like this:

```
let url = window.location.href;

['click','popstate', 'onload'].forEach( evt =>
        window.addEventListener(evt, function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
                if (url !== location.href) {
                    // do stuff
                }
                url = location.href;
            });
        }, true)
    );
```

Is there a better or more generic way to listen for page loads in a SPA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if URL has changed after hash in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-if-url-has-changed-after-hash-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/41825103/7042552 did the job for me, unbelievable we still have to use these hacks in 2018.

Answer (score 31):

Now that most browsers support [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), you can use code like this to detect URL changes in a SPA:

```js
let previousUrl = '';
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  if (location.href !== previousUrl) {
      previousUrl = location.href;
      console.log(`URL changed to ${location.href}`);
    }
});
const config = {subtree: true, childList: true};
observer.observe(document, config);
```

Comment: From what I can tell this won't work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158577/1540547

Comment: @jorgen it works, do you have more detail on what isn't working when you tried it?

Comment: Hello! When I tried it just didn't trigger on URL change. I didn't go deeply into it though, as I thought it wouldn't work after reading the above link, so I might be wrong.

Comment: You imitted `mutationObserver.observe(target, options)` - so your observer doesnt work

Comment: This is a bad solution, observing deeply nested element leads to performance issues, and this one observing the entire document tree!