# run Javascript function when I go to another page without reload

Tags: javascript

I'm a super-newbie with JS, so maybe the question is super stupid.
I got this JS that is started correctly in every page. but in some cases in this blog, I want to run the same script when I go to < mysite.com/page/2 > where the page is not reloaded but only the content change. 
I think I should use something like "hashchange" in the eventlistners but is not working, cause is not an hash.
I don't want to run the JS after a certain ammount of time, cause is a dirty solution, and I can't change the code cause is a wordpress template, I can only edit it trough JS.
any suggestion? 
I tried everything, in the event parameters: scroll, load, change, but nothing work, please give me suggestions. :(

waiting for yours, I leave you my code and the link on what I'm working in order to show you better the situation.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addStuff);
document.addEventListener("hashchange", addStuff); //<--- THIS IS NOT WORKING

function addStuff()
{
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("t-entry-cf-detail-106360");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].innerHTML = "<a href='http://www.filmidee.it/tag/" + x[i].innerHTML.replace(/\s+/g, '-') + "'>" + x[i].innerHTML + "</a>";
}
};
```

http://www.filmidee.it/screening/

Comment: What if you run this function when clicking on the links that changes from one page to another?

Comment: _"I want to run the same script when I go to < mysite.com/page/2 >"_ How do you go to "mysite.com/page/2"? What do you mean by "run the same script"?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: @MathiasW is not working.

Comment: @MauroAguilar I tried, it work only with some seconds of delay and just one time. 
like, I'm in page 1, I go in page 2, It works. but if I go back in page one, doesn't work. am I doing something wrong?
I just added this 
`var $pn= document.getElementsByClassName('page-numbers');
for(var i=0; i<$pn.length; i++) $lba[i].onclick = function(){
setTimeout(addStuff, 3000);
};`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a slightly different syntax according to this question: [How to detect URL change in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change-in-javascript)

```
window.onhashchange = addStuff;
```

A working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addStuff);
    window.onhashchange = addStuff;

    function addStuff()
    {
      console.log("called addStuff");
    }

    function processClick(){
        location.hash="myValue";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="processClick();"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...because the event [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange) happens to the window, not the DOM.

Comment: The hashchange doesn't work, even because the link that is generated doesn't contain any #
Isn't somewhere an event that trigger function when the URL change, not necessarly with  an # inside?

Comment: As a hack, can you just change the hash when the content changes?              location.hash="myValue";

Comment: Your idea @JohannesFilter was nice, but I can't edit the HTML in this moment. Actually I got another Idea who seems to work, but creating some delay so let me know what do you think. 
I used the trigger the function the animation inside the page and I add this two line 
`var $lba= document.getElementsByClassName('isotope-wrapper');
$lba[i].addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", addStuff);
$lba[i].addEventListener("animationend", addStuff);`
what do you think? any idea to make it lighter?

Comment: No, remotely debugging is hard. ;) I think you should make us of [Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for further Wordpress development. You can adjust everything and changes won't get overridden when updating.