# Listener event for when URL parameters change

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener, addeventlistener

I have a single page app with pagination and filters, and need to detect when the current URL changes at all.  Is there not a simple way to add a listener to the current URL and trigger something when it changes? (No setting intervals either!)

1. User lands on www.foobar.com
2. User does something, url changes to www.foobar.com?filter=hello
3. My function runs

I have tried both onhashchange, and tried unbeforeunload, and neither are relevant for this.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
   alert ('url changed!');
};

window.onhashchange = function() { 
alert ('url changed!');  
}
```

Is there a way to add a listener to the URL, and trigger something anytime it changes at all?   (again, single page app so no refresh)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect URL change in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change-in-javascript)

Comment: I looked at that -  thats an "onhashchange" scenario.  Mine is a bit different, no hashes, and i dont' want to set intervals.

Comment: @klugjo nope - as that has a has in the url. Here's just mere parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to use setInterval, you can override the `history.pushState` event:

```
(function(history){
    const pushState = history.pushState;
    history.pushState = function(state) {
        if (typeof history.onpushstate == "function") {
            history.onpushstate({state: state});
        }
        // Call your custom function here
        return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
    }
})(window.history);
```

Comment: this is getting close! although it gives me a console error of  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.   It might be conflicting with other code on the site...

Comment: why `History`, shouldt it be `history` ? no caps

Comment: Arrow functions do not expose an `arguments` object, you would have to use `history.pushState = (state, ...args) => {` and `pushState.call(history, state, ...args);`

Answer (score 9):

you can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe) to listen to URL changes amongst other things:

```js
let previousUrl = '';
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  if (window.location.href !== previousUrl) {
      previousUrl = window.location.href;
      console.log(`URL changed from ${previousUrl} to ${window.location.href}`);
    }
});
const config = {subtree: true, childList: true};

// start listening to changes
observer.observe(document, config);

// stop listening to changes
// observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: By using `MutationObserver` like this, you are not listening to URL changes, you are listening to changes to the DOM and trying to catch changes to the url as a possible side effect. But it is entirely possible for the url to change without the DOM changing at all.