# Vue - watch url without VueRouter

Tags: url, vue.js, watch

Is it possible to react on URL changes in a Vue component, without including VueRouter?

In case VueRouter is present, we can watch $route, however, my application does not rely on VueRouter.

```
export default {
    watch: { '$route': route => console.log(window.location.href) }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change-in-javascript

Comment: Is there any particular reason for for doing this? (I'm new to Vue, and I'm curious as to why one would want to avoid VueRouter.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before I used vue router, I did something like this...

```
data: function() {
  return {
     route: window.location.hash,
     page: 'home'
  }
},
watch: {
  route: function(){
    this.page = window.location.hash.split("#/")[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange) event for that. Poster was looking to watch `href`, it seems.