# How to stop accessing direct Thank you page? HTML and Javascript/AjaX

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a requirement here:

I don't want user to access Thank you page directly. If user want to access the Thank you page directly they should redirect back to Registration page, also Solution should not be cookies based and not be .htaccess based.

This page is HTML and javascript based.

Appreciate help in advance.

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See this as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change-in-javascript , and whenever url is changed check if it contains your thank you page context, if found then redirect the flow to registration or whatever page you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try with PHP form it will let go user after filing specific form