# .bind(haschange) isn't detecting a change in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm following the response from this page and it seems a very simple implementation, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected:

[How to detect URL change in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change-in-javascript)

The website I'm working with has a mailbox that changes the url every time I switch conversation threads. I want to inject a button into the conversation.

```
console.log('loaded')
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
     console.log('change detected')
});
```

when I open the page, the button loads into the current conversation (code not shown). However, when I click to a different conversation

`www.url.com/message/conversation/6509070457239584768` to `www.url.com/message/conversation/6508358521619308544`

the code doesn't seem to be executing. in the DevTools I see `loaded` but I do not see `changed detected`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any additional code I need to show that might be causing the problem?

Comment: What does it mean to click on on a different conversation? Is it a SPA or does it open a new page?

Comment: SPA, the url changes, which just changes which message thread I see

Comment: www.url.com/inbox/message/NUMBER

Comment: Take a look at the third answer from aljgom of your posted Link. He says that this doesn't work... Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought that was only for when the hash doesn't change. wouldn't the hash change because the conversation ID changes?

Comment: Uh, that's the path that is changing not a [hash part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Comment: There are "hash" trailed urls. like www.bla.com/xxx/yy/#123 if the #123 changes your event will be fired. It says "hash"changed not "has"changed... And thereby not the hash of the URL is meant but the part after '#' in the url...

Comment: that is what I didn't understand! thank you

Comment: you're welcome. it is better to speak of the fragment identifier because hash may lead to confusion if not known.

Comment: I didn't really understand these concepts and what it was doing. but now it makes sense. I implemented the "brute force" solution it and its