# Highlight current route item without clicking it

Tags: angular

I have menu items that can be clicked and takes to different routes. When route is changed by clicking on item, it stays highlighted. For example, click on Home, takes to url.com/home and Home button stays highlighted. But if I go directly to url.com/home, the Home button is not highlighted.

```
<li nz-menu-item routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">
   <span title><i nz-icon type="home"></i>Home</span>
 </li>   
<li nz-menu-item routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">
   <span title><i nz-icon type="info-circle"></i>About</span>
 </li>
```

How to change it that item is highlighted any time when the specific route is open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using ng-zorro you can use the `nzSelected` property for your `li` tag to determine if it should be highlighted or not. Inject `Router` in your components typescript and check if the current url is matching the menu-item

HTML

```
<li nz-menu-item [nzSelected]="this.isSelected('/home')" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">
   <span title><i nz-icon type="home"></i>Home</span>
 </li>   
<li nz-menu-item [nzSelected]="this.isSelected('/about')" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">
   <span title><i nz-icon type="info-circle"></i>About</span>
 </li>
```

TS

```
constructor(private router: Router)
...

isSelected(route: string): boolean {
    return route === this.router.url;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `ng-zorro-antd`-package in version 10 there is a property called `[nzMatchRouter]` on `nz-menu-items` which sets `nzSelected` according to the routerlink

https://ng.ant.design/components/menu/en#%5Bnz-menu-item%5D

With this you dont need any additional typescript as @kounex mentioned

```html
<li nz-menu-item routerLink="/home" [nzMatchRouter]="true" routerLinkActive="active">
   <span title><i nz-icon type="home"></i>Home</span>
 </li>   
<li nz-menu-item routerLink="/about" [nzMatchRouter]="true" routerLinkActive="active">
   <span title><i nz-icon type="info-circle"></i>About</span>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not supposed to touch the URL yourself. When you do so, you do not send routing events to Angular.

Try navigating twice to the URL, this will reload your page : with this, your app reloads, effectively sending routing events.

If you wish to implement the desired behavior, you will have to [listen to URL changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change-in-javascript) and reload your actual route.