# How to Detect route change in angular 6 application using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular6

I have a Angular 6 application , Im able to detect route change through angular logic, 
But i have a requirement to detect changes through **Javascript or Jquery script**,
When ever there is a change in route we need to trigger a javascript function.

Please help me, Thank you in advance

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41825103/7042552 , I think you can find the answer here

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I was able to detect the URL change and trigger an event using Javascript in Angular7:

```
 var oldLocation= '';
  var newLocation= '';

setInterval(() => {
      init();
    }, 500);
init() {
    this.newLocation = window.location.pathname;
    if (oldLocation !== newLocation) {
      EventTrigger();
      oldLocation = newLocation;
    }
  }

  EventTrigger() {
    console.log(this.newLocation, this.oldLocation);
  }
```

Comment: Actually i need to trigger a event/function when ever there is a change in route, 
Your logic can be used with in the function to get the current route information