# JavaScript - Get url from window without submitting it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, routes, window

So I have a page that I want to retrieve the URL from but I want to get the current text that is written there regardless of if the url was submitted or not (imagine if the user entered a page and decided to change the val=sfbdjkfg directly through the url but didn't submit it )

So `window.location.href` is not what I want because I have to submit to get the URL

Is there any way to do this?
What about using a javaScript framework that uses dynamic routes?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change-in-javascript

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi — That doesn't help. The URL isn't changing. The question is about when the user edits the text in the address bar but never presses Enter to confirm it.

Comment: @user1678 There's no physical ability to do this, with frameworks or not. URL input field is not a part of the page but a part of browser UI. Your app doesn't have access to browser UI, unless it's browser extension. Allowing websites to spy on client's next destination would be a major privacy and security breach. Think of it this way, as long as a user doesn't submit the address, it's none of your website's business what a user types there.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such way via javascript to interact with browser UI components such as URL bar or "add as bookmark" button unless your browser provides that.
Browser itself act as a wrapper/client that provides specific APIs and surely not to open gates to access the outside of it, for security reasons.

Comment: What about using JS frameworks and using dynamic routes?

Comment: @user1678 you can track event on route changes only ONCE you submit/confirm.
keypress event would not be tracked