# Detect page change from browser navigation bar

Tags: javascript

I am presented with the following problem:
In my current web application with current browsers, the user can type in the navigation bar the name of a certain page: stackoverflow.com, when the user presses the enter button, before being redirected to the page in question, I need to update the status of a record in the database.
I have tried some events in the body but if the user does it this way it does not detect them.

I have also followed the following options without success.
[How to detect if URL has changed after hash in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-if-url-has-changed-after-hash-in-javascript/52809105#52809105)

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure it will resolve your problem but you could probably send your database update request in the window.onbeforeunload event like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes, with this event I manage to get all the data and send it to the server. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help, could you please accept my answer ^^.https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers