# Run JS with "matches" even if the page doesnt refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a school project/ Chrome extension that assists the Checkout progress of a Website,
i declared in my mainfest.json that a content.js file should run if it matches a certain URL.

```
"content_scripts": [
         {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.solebox.com/de_DE/checkout?stage=payment*"
            ],
            "js": ["payment.js"]
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.solebox.com/de_DE/checkout?stage=placeOrder*"
            ],
            "js": ["placeorder.js"]
```

as you can see in the link, there are different stages. So from stage "payment" to stage "place order" the page won't refresh, ergo the script won´t notice that the URL changed so the js cant be executed.
Is there any way the chrome extension can always check the URL?

Comment: You might find this question helpful. A good way to manage these cases is to use hash to change the location URL without triggering a reload https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-if-url-has-changed-after-hash-in-javascript

Comment: See also [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Answer (score 0):

You could use try using `webNavigation`. Just check the tab-url and inject your desired script based on that.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.get(tab.tabId, function (results) {
        if (results.url.match("some URL")) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
                file: "someScript.js" 
            });
        } 
    });
});
```

You can read about the webNavigation API [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#event-onBeforeNavigate)

Comment: okay but i where should i paste it? because the manifest.json file isn't javascript

Comment: just add a background-script to the manifest file and then add this stuff in the background.js file. Here is a link to an explanation: https://dev.to/michaeldscherr/building-a-simple-chrome-extension-1mal