# Bootstrap Collapse - open the given id fragment

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, fragment-identifier

Imagine a [Bootstrap collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) with 3 parts

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    ...
    <div id="accordionOne" class="panel-heading"></div>
    ...
    <div id="accordionTwo" class="panel-heading"></div>
    ...
    <div id="accordionThree" class="panel-heading"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to make the plugin open the given [HTTP fragment identifier](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#scroll-to-fragid) ?

Example `http://myproject/url#accordionTwo` would open the second accordion

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$("#accordionTwo").collapse('show');
```

To open the given HTTP fragment identifier, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var anchor = window.location.hash;
    $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
    $(anchor).collapse('show');
});
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed by bart in the comments:
be careful with targeting `.collapse` because this class is also used for the navigation bar when the viewport is `xs`.

Comment: Thank you, I know that I can open it with javascript and even without (using the class `in`). The question is about controlling the opened part from the HTTP fragment identifier.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can improve this by deleting the `.replace("#", "")` part and just selecting the element to show with `$(anchor)`

Comment: Be careful with targeting `.collapse` because this class is also used for the navigation bar when the viewport is `xs`.

Answer (score 8):

This line will open the correct hash

```
location.hash && $(location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
```

Answer (score 5):

Yet another solution, a bit smaller and compact:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var anchor = window.location.hash;
  $(anchor).collapse('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For really simple and quick to implement hash routing, you could try something like [Routie](http://projects.jga.me/routie/)

```
routie({
    accordionOne: function() {
        $('#accordionOne').collapse('show');
    },
    accordionTwo: function() {
        $('#accordionTwo').collapse('show');
    },
    accordionThree: function() {
        $('#accordionThree').collapse('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: There is the [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange) event, but it's not supported by every browser. If you want to do this without adding another dependency, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161906/handle-url-anchor-change-event-in-js