# How can I load new content without reloading the page based on hashtags fragments?

Tags: javascript

Imagine I'm on:

http://example.com/

I click in a link containing a hashbang [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), let's say:

http://example.com/#!/login

I would like it to show the login form without reloading the page. How is this done?

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: Use Ajax (XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Are you asking how you can redirect users to a loginpage if they are not yet logged in? Have a look at sessions.

Comment: How does this have to do with hashtags? Also in a StackOverflow question make sure you have a question mark somewhere.

Comment: In modern browsers it is possible to do this entirely with CSS, without using JavaScript at all. Are CSS solutions acceptable, or are you necessarily looking to do this with JavaScript?

Comment: @JeremyBanks how can you do this with CSS?

Comment: You can only do this with CSS if you have all content pre-loaded on the page, CSS won't get you any new content without reloading.

Comment: I thing @JeremyBanks misunderstood the question.

Comment: In many cases, such as when you're using a front-end templating system like backbone (suggested below), you will probably have all of your content in client-side templates or hidden elements ("pre-loaded") already. Sending a new HTTP request to the server just so you can grab a tiny login form is not very efficient or elegant if you have an alternative.

Comment: This is not called a "hashtag". A "hashtag" is a tag, usually in a post body, which is prefixed by the hash character, as popularized on twitter. What you are asking can be done with any type of URL fragment identifier -- the part that follows the `#`. The `#!/` syntax, sometimes referred to as a *hashbang* fragment (and also popularized by Twitter) is a particular type of fragment identifier -- and the detail of whether you use that or any other fragment is probably not relevant to your question.

Comment: But at the same time, when you are using BackboneJS, there is no need to write your own CSS rules to hide or show things, as BackboneJS takes care of hiding (removing from the DOM) and showing (appending to the DOM) views for you.

Comment: I probably gave the wrong example... See please: http://papademo.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to find out how to load new content without refreshing the page, then maybe move on to [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/) and use its routers to get the hash thing working.

**Edit:**

Here's a [tutorial](http://backbonetutorials.com/), I'm not going to write one for you. But it comes down to having a server side which is able to provide the needed content for you (a log in form), whether it does so asynchronously or synchronously is besides the point. Then using a Backbone Router which will read the hash bang and call the right JavaScript function based on this hash bang, this JavaScript function should live inside a Backbone Controller, and it should handle the instantiating of a new Backbone View and adding it to the DOM. The Backbone View could be added to a predefined Backbone Region, and could be loading an [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) template to make things even easier.

Comment: I think BackboneJS is the answer but I couldn't understand yet how it exactly works

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a much simpler solution you should take a look at another concise answer here: [Handle URL anchor change event in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161906/handle-url-anchor-change-event-in-js). In summary, you periodically check `window.location.hash` for changes and run your javascript to bring up the login content.