# What is the event to listen to for jumping within page without reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm writing a small documentation, html being like:

```html
<dl class="commands">
  <dt id="commandA">Command A</dt>
  <dd class="description">This command makes you happy.</dd>
  <dt id="commandB">Command B</dt>
  <dd class="description">This command makes you even happier.</dd>
</dl>
```

I thought it would be nice if accessing `mydoc.html#commandA` highlights where the description for `command A` is written, and wrote the following JavaScript:

```js
(function(){
  window.addEventListener('load', emphCmd);
  
  function emphCmd(){
    var loc = window.location.href;
    if (/\.html#.*$/.test(loc)){
      var cmd = loc.split("#")[1]; // "commandA" for mydoc.html#commandA
      var cmdElm = document.getElementById(cmd);
      if (cmdElm !== null){ // if element with that id is found,
        cmdElm.style.backgroundColor = "#eeeeaa"; // highlight its background.
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

This works, but only when the page is loaded (well, of course. I said do this on `load`). The cases where this script does nothing includes : i) when I manually add `#commandA` to the address bar in the browser and press Enter (without <kbd>F5</kbd> --- reloading) ii) Jumping within page with `<a>` tag.

I want it to be highlighted in either case. For the `<a href="#commandA">`, I could probably`anchor.addEventListener('click',emphCmd)`, although that does not seem very neat.

Is there an event for these "jumping within page"? If not, what are the good ways to achieve this effect?

Comment: I think the `scroll` event is what you want.

Comment: @Barmar That event fires just by scrolling, right? Although that won't cause problems in this case because what's after `#` is always checked, am I right to understand that there is no special ways for "jumping, not scrolling"?

Comment: I'm not totally sure. I think it might fire for anything that causes the window to reposition, not just using the scrollbar. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: Your requirement is just highlight the targeted part (the part is jumped to), so in this case you don't need to listen to any event, just add the style for `:target` in CSS to highlight it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wfszzx2k/

Comment: @KingKing Wow, CSS3 literally rocks. I can accept as the answer if you post that alongside with `scroll` (or any other good) event..

Comment: it's OK. In fact I could not think of any event pinpointing exactly your desired event, so anyway the demo I posted is just a work-around (a beautiful one).

Comment: @KingKing Will you be posting an answer? This is an interesting enough problem to solve that I wouldn't mind creating a community wiki post, if you won't be posting an answer.

Comment: ok, you can freely make a wiki post.

Comment: Why this is not helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161906/handle-url-anchor-change-event-in-js

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos This IS helpful, I just couldn't find it --- I didn't come up with digging around hash, not movement. Although using css seems cleaner in this specific use case, `hashchange` event is the more general solution. Will you add that to the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one single event that would cover your use-case, but since you're just attempting to style a targeted element, you can actually leverage the `:target` CSS pseudo-class. The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) has a pretty good description and some examples:

> URIs with fragment identifiers link to a certain element within the
>   document, known as the target element. For instance, here is a URI
>   pointing to an anchor named section2:
>   http://example.com/folder/document.html#section2 The anchor can be any
>   element with an id attribute, e.g. `<h1 id="section2">` in our example.
>   The target element h1 can be represented by the :target pseudo-class.

The `:target` pseudo-class also works with named anchors (i.e. `<a name="some-id-value"></a>`), so it's backward-compatible with older markup. You will notice, though, that using a named anchor is **not** 100% the same - the targeted item receives the rule, and an anchor is an inline element.

Here's @KingKing's example, included as a code snippet:

```css
:target {
  background: #eeeeaa;
}
```

```html
<a href="#commandA">Command A</a>
<a href="#commandB">Command B</a>
<a href="#commandC">Command C</a>
<dl class="commands">
  <dt id="commandA">Command A</dt>
  <dd class="description">This command makes you happy.</dd>
  <dt id="commandB">Command B</dt>
  <dd class="description">This command makes you even happier.</dd>
  <dt><a name="commandC">Command C</a></dt>
  <dd class="description">This command makes you sad, since it's using a named anchor.</dd>
</dl>
```

The one caveat is that IE8 and under do not support the `:target` selector. You can get around that by using a polyfill such as [Selectivir](http://selectivizr.com/) or [IE9.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).