# javascript url hashtag change unload event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write a jQuery event

```
$(window).unload(function() {
            console.log('cool');
        });
```

When I close the tab then unload event will be trigger.

But, When I change my Url http:/localhost/#home to http:/localhost/#profile.

Unload event doesn't work. Why?

Comment: The page doesn't unload when the url hash fragment changes.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161906/handle-url-anchor-change-event-in-js) may help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the page isn't unload. The hash is used to anchor elements or to design a single page layout for all application. You must to change your event to `hashchange`

```
  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    // stuff
  });
```