# Javascript function on url change of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html page (http://www.autoelettric.com/info/SafeConversionToLed.html) that when I click on button the status bar on top will change.
The site would be designed for easy navigation through the buttons, but if an user uses the scroll, the status bar is not updated. So I would like to know if can I do an event that updates the status bar on the change of url (httt.url.com # step1, httt.url.com # step2, httt.url.com # step3).

For example, my code now: 
Script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function status0()
    {
        document.getElementById("imgStausBar").src ="status0.png";
    }
    function status1()
    {
        document.getElementById("imgStausBar").src ="status1.png";
    } 
    function status2()
    {
        document.getElementById("imgStausBar").src ="status2.png";
    } 
    function status3()
    {
        document.getElementById("imgStausBar").src ="status3.png";
    } 
</script>
```

Html

```
<a href="#FlasherUnit" onclick="status1()"><div class="btn-5" width="50px">↓ START</div></a>
<a href="#ExactPower" onclick="status3()"><div class="btn-5" width="50px">→ YES</div></a>
<a href="#FlasherUnit" onclick="status1()"><div class="btn-5-previous" width="50px">↩ PREVIOUS</div></a>
<a href="#SafeConversion" onclick="status0()"><div class="btn-5-top" width="10px">↑</div></a>
```

What I would do:

```
 if current url is #SafeConversion do status0()
 if current url is #FlasherUnit do status1()
 if current url is #ExactPower do status2()
 etc...
```

---

EDIT:

I added this, but it doesn't work.

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) { // event supported?
    window.onhashchange = function () {
        hashChanged(window.location.hash);
    }
}
else {
    var locationHash = window.location.hash;

    window.setInterval(function () {
        if(locationHash == "#SafeConversion") {
            status0();
        } else if(locationHash == "#FlasherUnit") {
           status1();
        } else if(locationHash == "#ExactPower") {
           status2();
        } else if(locationHash == "#ExactPower") {
           status2();
        } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution") {
           status3();
        } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution2") {     
           status3();
        } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution2/1") {     
           status3();
        } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution3") {     
          status3();
        } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution3/1") {     
          status3();
        } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution4") {     
          status3();
        } else if(locationHash == "#Contact") {     
          status0();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle URL anchor change event in js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161906/handle-url-anchor-change-event-in-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hashChanged(locationHash) {
    if(locationHash == "#SafeConversion") {
        status0();
    } else if(locationHash == "#FlasherUnit") {
        status1();
    } else if(locationHash == "#ExactPower") {
        status2();
    } else if(locationHash == "#ExactPower") {
        status2();
    } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution") {
        status3();
    } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution2") {     
        status3();
    } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution2/1") {     
        status3();
    } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution3") {     
        status3();
    } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution3/1") {     
        status3();
    } else if(locationHash == "#YourSolution4") {     
        status3();
    } else if(locationHash == "#Contact") {     
        status0();
    } 
}

if ("onhashchange" in window) { // event supported?
    window.onhashchange = function () {
        hashChanged(window.location.hash);
    }
}
else { // event not supported:
    var storedHash = window.location.hash;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
            storedHash = window.location.hash;
            hashChanged(storedHash);
        }
    }, 100);
}

</script>
```

Comment: I added this code, but it doesn't work.. I upload the page on site, you can try..  ( http://www.autoelettric.com/info/SafeConversionToLed.html )

Comment: I add the { after the function... now is working. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the url, when you said status bar, i tried it and the status bar updated when i scroll-up or down.

Comment: No, I think he means the progress bar that is at the top of the page

Comment: but only if you use the button.. if you scroll (with the mouse on pc and with a finger on mobile) the status bar isn't updated

Answer (score -1):

use "window.location.hash"

```
var locationHash = window.location.hash;
if(locationHash == "#SafeConversion") {
    status0();
} else if(locationHash == "#FlasherUnit") {
    status1()
}
```

and so on....

Comment: And where can I add this? On <script>...</script> in <head> section?

Comment: @Vilias Kumkar, I added but doesn't work (view my edit code in question)..

Comment: No, I don't tink. But I have to call this function() anywhere? @Vilias Kumkar

Comment: @MarikaF. Would mind to bundle you all code in fiddle and share over?

Comment: Of course you need to call the function, you need to insert in a setInterval() so every x milliseconds (100 should be ok) it check the location hash

Comment: @rpadovani How can I do this? I added window.setInterval(function () {...my if...}, 100);