# How to trigger javascript when a page is loaded to a specific div ID?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following div:

```
<div id="tutorial" onclick="console.log('Triggered tutorial');"></div>
```

I want to target this div via the URL, by navigating like this:

```
mysite.com/mypage.html#tutorial
```

However, loading the page to this div ID doesn't trigger the onclick event.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you post your full code somewhere? A snippet out of context doesn't help us help you. Pastebin or Codepen are both great places for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onload

```
<div id="tutorial" onload="onLoadTutorial();"></div>

function onLoadTutorial() {
  if (document.location.endsWith("#tutorial")) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling hashChanged(), call your own onclick function or execute the content inside of it

[Handle URL anchor change event in js](http://like%20this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161906/handle-url-anchor-change-event-in-js))